# Color picker is broken? 100% red with 50% green is pure yellow? Identical to 100% red with 100% green? Nonlinear RGB scaling?

Tags: color

Is there some complexity to how the color picker works? I can't make sense of it. If I select 100% red and 100% green, this should represent pure yellow and it does.

However, if I also select 100% red and 50% green, this also creates pure yellow.

I only move away from pure yellow once I drop the green considerably more. In an RBG system, 100% red and 50% green is most definitely not pure yellow.

Is there some perceptual curving or nonlinear scaling of the values in this color picker and if so, how does it work or scale? Is there any way to use a traditional RBG or HSV color picker?

This link suggests RBG should be linear but it is either broken or this is false: [HSV to RGB conversion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80034/hsv-to-rgb-conversion)

I used Just Color Picker (Free) to sample the displayed color in Blender with both settings and it is identical:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does this page of the Blender 3.2 Manual help?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/color_picker.html?highlight=color%20picker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color channel values in Blender go from 0 to 1 so if you enter values greater than 1, that's "fine" and Blender will use those values, but they cannot be displayed so they get clipped at some point and the same color is displayed.

Note that it's not good practice to use colors with values greater than 1 in Blender. If you do that in your shaders, they may not behave in a predictable and realistic way and your renders might have more noise. However there may be plenty of situations you might want to use something that was meant to be color information for something else in Blender and then the ability to input any values(even negative for example) is great.